# Wait for javascript to render element into DOM to then see the height of the appended element

Tags: javascript

Suggested answers to posted questions don't really show a solution to a very common issue. I haven't seen a method of having javascript render an element into the DOM and then looping back to read the properties of the inserted element.

I'm working on a custom text scroller. My code appends divs with the words from an array like so:

```
wordsArray.forEach((word, index) => {
    $('#adjective').append(`<div style='opacity: ${index === 0 ? 1 : 0};'>${word}</div>`)
})
```

Without explicitly stating the height of the div, I'd like to read the div's height once it's already painted in the DOM. I'd like the forEach loop to finish, to then read one of the divs inside #adjective element. I don't want to use setTimeout.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could use a recursive `setTimeout` that checks if the `childCount` of `#adjective` has changed. It's not ideal, but it seems the simplest and most performance-friendly way in my mind. Things like `MutationObserver` would almost certainly be overkill.

Comment: Could you show more of your code? Where in the file are you attempting to get the height of the appended div? As long as you do it anywhere below your forEach loop, you should be getting the correct value. But of course I might be missing something because I don't have the full context.

Comment: something like `const firstChild = $('#adjective').append(wordsArray.map((word, index) => \`<div style='opacity: ${index === 0 ? 1 : 0};'>${word}</div>\`).join('')).children().first();` ?